# Batch Script to Rename Files Not Working (Sometimes)

Tags: file, for-loop, batch-file, special-characters, rename

I have a batch script that loops through files in a directory and will rename the file if it matches one of four patterns.  When I run this in my test environment it works perfectly.  However, when I run it in proudction it only renames the first file it encounters.  I run them both from my pc against directories on mapped drives.

I thought the problem may have to do with one of the file names I'm searching for containing a "+" sign, but this doesn't pose a problem when I run the script in test.

The file path for the directory I want to search is passed as a parameter.  It is the only parameter.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

My code is below:

```
@ECHO OFF
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
REM ******************************************************************************************
REM 
REM            Name: get_current_foldername.bat
REM   Description: This script will rename generic loan review sample file names such as CRE.xls, 
REM                Family.xls, etc. to [docket]_[yyyymmdd]_[hhmmss]_[list type (cre, fam1-4, etc.)].xls.
REM                Ex. 13346_20121220_125930_cre.xls.  
REM                This script is used by Globalscape as part of the completed loan review sample upload.
REM    Parameters: There is one parameter passed.  
REM                The first parameter contains the path where the source file exists.
REM          Author: Joe Mannetta
REM            Date: 01/28/13
REM 
REM ******************************************************************************************
REM ******************************************************************************************
REM 
REM  Set CurrPath variable to parameter value.
REM  Set CurrDirName variable to the current directory name.  This excludes higher level folders.
REM 
REM ******************************************************************************************
SET CurrPath=%1%
FOR %%* in (%CurrPath%) DO (SET CurrDirName=%%~n*)
REM ECHO Current Path is: %CurrPath%
REM ECHO New DIR NAME is: %CurrDirName%
REM ******************************************************************************************
 CD %CurrPath% 
 REM ECHO CurrPath is %CurrPath%
 GOTO LOOP
 REM *****************************************************************************************
 REM LOOP Function
 REM Loops through files in directory and go to Rename function if the file name matches CRE.xls, FAMILY.xls, FAMILY5+.xls, or HELOCS.xls.
 REM *****************************************************************************************
 :LOOP
REM Get name of 1st file in list. Note this also returns the full file path.
 FOR /F "delims= tokens=1" %%f in ('dir /b *.xls') DO ( 
REM FOR /F "tokens=1" %%f IN ('dir /o-d /b %CurrPath%') DO ( 
  SET File=%%f
 ECHO File is: %%f
 IF %%f==CRE.xls GOTO RENAME
 IF %%f==FAMILY.xls GOTO RENAME
 IF %%f==FAMILY5+.xls GOTO RENAME
 IF %%f==HELOCS.xls GOTO RENAME
 REM ECHO %%f
 REM ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
 GOTO END
REM ECHO Did NOT Make it to GOTO
 )
REM ******************************************************************************************
REM RENAME Function
REM Renames the file to [folder name]_[yyyymmdd]_[hhmmss]_[CRE|FAMILY|FAMILY5+|HELOCS].xls
REM  Date is reformatted to yyyymmdd.  Time is reformatted to hhmmss.  Some credit due to Jimmy Selix at http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/956/windows-batch-file-bat-to-get-current-date-in-mmddyyyy-format/ for date and time formatting.
REM ******************************************************************************************
:RENAME
REM End loop so that File variable is set to the newest file.   
  REM Drop file path to isolate the file name.
  SET CurrFName=!File:%CurrPath%=!
  REM ECHO CurrFName is %CurrFName%
REM Set date to yyyymmdd format.
 SET dt=!date:~10,4!!date:~4,2!!date:~7,2!
REM Set time to hhmmss format. Include leading zeros for single digit times.
 SET mytime=%TIME: =0%
 SET hhmmss=!mytime:~0,2!!mytime:~3,2!!mytime:~6,2!
 SET NewFName=!CurrDirName!_!dt!_!hhmmss!_!CurrFName!
REM echo !CurrPath!\!CurrFName! !CurrPath!\!NewFName!
REM Set new file name and rename file.
 COPY "!CurrPath!\!CurrFName!" "!CurrPath!\!NewFName!"
 COPY "!CurrPath!\!NewFName!" "!CurrPath!\..\..\archive"
 DEL /Q !CurrPath!\!CurrFName!
 REM ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
 GOTO LOOP
 REM *******************************************************************************************
 :END
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to dig through.  Can you narrow it down to just the part that's causing the problem?  There's more chance you'll find someone willing to help out if we only have to read a dozen lines of code.  Rule of thumb: if a scrollbar is necessary for your code block, it's probably too much code.

Answer (score 2):

Aaaaack!

Your major problem is that you are using GOTO within the FOR/F...%%f loop.

- REMOVE the `GOTO End` completely.
- CHANGE EACH `GOTO RENAME` to `CALL :RENAME` (the colon IS significant - it specifies calling an internal routine)
- ADD a `GOTO :EOF` statement after the final close-parenthesis of the FOR/f...%%f loop
- REPLACE the `GOTO LOOP` in the :RENAME routine with `GOTO :EOF`

A few notes:

- Batch does not see a label as an end-of-procedure like, say, Pascal. It simply charges on through...(hence `GOTO LOOP`/REMs/`:LOOP` is redundant)
- EOF is pre-defined as 'physical end-of-file' so there is no need for a :END label. Reaching end-of-file will terminate the batch or cause a CALL to return
- `SET var=%1%` is INCORRECT (but not fatally so) The corrrect form is `SET var=%1`
- %%* works, but is not "official" - why not use one of the documented 26 lower-case and 26 upper-case letters?
- RENAME is a poor choice of name for a routine because the REN command is an alternative for RENAME (ie it's a batch keyword)

Comment: Peter, thanks for your critique.  I'll make the change you recommended and let you know how it goes.  As you can probably tell, I'm by no means an expert in writing batch files.

Comment: That didn't fix the problem but it did help me figure out what's wrong.  For some reason the file list is not being retained.  The script loops through the file list, finds a match and renames it, but then it executes the dir command of the FOR loop again.  Since the renamed file is at the top of the list, it just keeps looping through the routine and starting over.